# Windows 8 administrator's account permissions have been reduced to guest's account

Tags: windows-8, permissions, administrator

Some reason I am unable to do simple tasks like change time or uninstall a program.

Here is the list of user accounts:

[image: Account List]

Comment: Please provide more information. The question as it stands is unlikely to be answered.

Comment: @SuperBoss - If you cannot change the time it means your not logging into an `Administrator` level account.

Comment: @Simon I'd be happy to provide more information. What do you need?

Comment: @Ramhound Any idea on how to log into Administrator level account? There is only one account in the system. This is how my User Accounts window look http://i.stack.imgur.com/tcBBY.png

Comment: @SuperBoss - Use the built-in `Administrator` account.

Comment: @Ramhound I enabled built-in Administrator account and logged in... No luck, the only difference is that I can change the time now. Still unable to press "Manage another account" or "Change User Account Control settings" or even uninstall a program.

Comment: @SuperBoss - Does the command to modify users work? Try doing the following `Win+X,G` **Computer Management** -> **System Tools**-> **Local Users and Groups** also read: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731745.aspx

Comment: @Ramhound yes, I am able to modify users with this tools. But how can fix the problem using them?

Comment: @SuperBoss - Change the permissions on the user in question that isn't working.

Comment: It doesn't work even for built-in Administrator account. I also don't know what to change :(

Answer (score 0):

Follow thos steps:

> 1. Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to display Settings.
> 2. Click the Power Options icon.
> 3. Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> Key while you click the Restart option.
> 4. On the first screen, select Troubleshoot.
> 5. On the next screen, select Advanced Options.
> 6. On the next screen, select Startup Settings. Click the Restart Button.
> 7. Press the Number <kbd>4</kbd> Key.
>
> The computer will start in Safe Mode.
>
> Click the Arrow Icon.
>
> Select the Administrator account.
>
> After Safe Mode starts, open Control Panel / User Accounts.
>
> Select Manage another account and select the account you wish to
>   change to an Administrator account.
>
> Select Change Account Type.
>
> Select the Administrator option and click the Change account type
>   button.
>
> Exit Control Panel and Restart the computer.
>
> Log on with your Administrator account.

**Source:**

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprosecurity/thread/06603cf8-f537-422b-b2a6-4aebe6eaad25/#26b79ecc-cbb4-40ed-8d84-854da1671689

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, when I press Manage another account nothing happens. http://i.stack.imgur.com/tcBBY.png

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry about that. I'm on Windows 8 64-bit Enterprise.